# Is it possible in DotNetNuke that all static content on site gets automatically uploaded on CDN?

Tags: dotnetnuke, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

I have a website created in DotNetNuke and have a Cloudfront CDN.

Is it possible for DNN that any static content (i.e. images etc.) which is uploaded and used on the website gets uploaded on CDN and their respective URLs gets translated to those from CDN automatically.

For example: I upload abc.jpg on the website and use it on a page as follows:

```
<img src="images/abc.jpg">
```

Now DNN should automatically push this image to Cloudfront and hence the URL should now be like:

```
<img src="xx.s3.amazonaws.com/images/abc.jpg">
```

Is it possible to achieve such functionality in DNN?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put the whole side behind CloudFront? It supports POST/PUT methods as well as dynamic objects (Cache-Control: no-cache).